# Python - efficient representation of pixels and associated values

Tags: python, data-structures, matrix, numpy, sparse-matrix

I'm using python to work with large-ish (approx 2000 x 2000) matrices, where each `I`, `J` point in the matrix represents a single pixel.

The matrices themselves are sparse (ie a substantial portion of them will have zero values), but when they are updated they tend to be increment operations, to a large number of adjacent pixels in a rectangular 'block', rather than random pixels here or there (a property i do not currently use to my advantage..). 
Afraid a bit new to matrix arithmetic, but I've looked into a number of possible solutions, including the various flavours of `scipy` sparse matrices. So far co-ordinate (COO) matrices seem to be the most promising. 
So for instance where I want to increment one block shape, I'd have to do something along the lines of:

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> from numpy import array
>>> I = array([0,0,0,0])
>>> J = array([0,1,2,3])
>>> V = array([1,1,1,1])
>>> incr_matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)),shape=(100,100))
>>> main_matrix += incr_matrix  #where main_matrix was previously defined
```

In the future, i'd like to have a richer pixel value representation in anycase (tuples to represent RGB etc), something that numpy array doesnt support out of the box (or perhaps I need to use [this](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-April/041801.html)).

Ultimately i'll have a number of these matrices that I would need to do simple arithmitic on, and i'd need the code to be as efficient as possible -- and distributable, so i'd need to be able to persist and exchange these objects in a small-ish representation without substantial penalties. I'm wondering if this is the right way to go, or should I be looking rolling my own structures using `dicts` etc?

Comment: I doubt that you could produce something better than scipy and numpy capabilities. But I am not enough skilled in them to be more affirmative. By the way, I dislike the use of the word 'vector'. On one hand, there is no built-in data structure named 'vector' in Python. On the other hand, a bidimensional table is unlikely to be called 'vector' in the mathematical sense. So, your entity is nor a Python object named 'vector', nor a mathematical structure called 'vector'

Comment: that is true - it should indeed say matrix instead of vector (?) :)

Comment: 2000x2000 isn't very big at all. There's no need to use sparse arrays. You should get much better performance out of just using normal numpy arrays. And incidentally, numpy _very_ much supports "something like" RGB "vectors" for each pixel... It's just a 2000x2000x3 array! It works _very_ well, and it's _very_ efficient!

Comment: I agree with Joe.  indexing every update may be more expensive than compressing the array when it's finally time to store it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule is, get the code working first, then optimize if needed...

In this case, use a normal numpy 2000x2000 array, or 2000x2000x3 for RGB.  This will be much easier and faster to work with, is only a small memory requirement, and has many other advantages, for example, you can use the standard image processing tools, etc.

Then, if needed, "to persist and exchange these objects", you can just compress them using gzip, pytables, jpeg, or whatever, but there's no need to limit your data manipulation based storage requirements.

This way you get both **faster processing** and **better compression**.

Comment: The code is indeed working with a standard array, but the 2000 x 2000 is over 140MB (~40KB zipped) and thats much to large to efficiently use for me, which is why ive been looking into the sparse matrices.

Comment: What are the elements in the 2000x2000 matrix?  For me, a 2000x2000 matrix of uint8 is 4MB.  (Just to be clear, maybe you do need a sparse matrix, but, in general, some questions on SO are missing a detail, and some need to approach the problem differently, so one just needs to sort this out.  I'm not sure which is going on here, but something doesn't quite seem to fit.)

Comment: i'm using float64s - but I think given this very helpful thread, it does seem that using sparse matrices at all is probably not the right way to go at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would say, yes, this is the way to go.  Definitely over building something out of dictionaries!  When building a "vector", array, then use a structured array, i.e. define your own dtype:

```
rgbtype = [('r','uint8'),('g','uint8'),('b','uint8')]
```

when incrementing your blocks, it will look something like this:

```
main_matrix['r'][blk_slice] += incr_matrix['r']
main_matrix['g'][blk_slice] += incr_matrix['g']
main_matrix['b'][blk_slice] += incr_matrix['b']
```

**Update:**

It looks like you can't do matrix operations with a coo_matrix, they exist simply as a convenient way to populate a sparse matrix.  You have to convert them to another (sparse) matrix type before doing the updates.  **[documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html)**

Comment: Or just use a mxnx3 array. Especially for image data, an `m x n x numbands` array is nicer way to handle things than a structured array as it lets you separate the bands more easily (`x[...,1]` instead of `x['r'].reshape(m,n)`). There's certainly nothing wrong with using a structured array, I just personally find simple 3D arrays a better match for image data. Either way, +1 from me.

Comment: I'm not sure if/how you do that with a sparse matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot we were talking about sparse matrixes when I made the comment... Sparse matrixes are inherently 2D, so you can't. Structured sparse arrays are definitely the way to go in that case. I still maintain that it would be better to avoid using a sparse matrix if he's going to be incrementing several blocks of it, but that's a different question altogether...

Comment: @joe why do you not recommend using sparse matrices? pickling the standard ones is resulting in very large intermediary memory requirements (c. 140MB per matrix), and that is what I was attempting to optimize by using a sparse matrix..

Comment: @flyingcrab - Arithmetic operations on sparse matrices will be _much_ slower than on dense arrays, unless the matrices are exceptionally sparse.  (Also, only `lil_matrix`'s support the sort of indexing you want to do, and one of their drawbacks is slow arithmetic operations). If you're worried about intermediary memory requirements, don't `pickle` the matrices! Use `numpy.save(...)`. Pickling does require large amounts intermediate memory, which is why `numpy.save` and `numpy.savez` exist. Overall, I just think that sparse matrices are the wrong answer to your problem... Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider looking into a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) as an implementation.  The quadtree structure is pretty efficient at storing sparse data, and has the added advantage that if you're working with structures composed of lots of blocks of similar data the representation can be very compact.  I'm not sure if this will be particularly applicable to what you're doing, since I don't know what you mean by "working in blocks," but it's certainly worth checking out as an alternative sparse matrix implementation.